# Looking for a statement ascribed to the Chofetz Chaim

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzedakah-charity, chofetz-chaim

The Artscroll Machzor for Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur notes in the footnotes to U’nesaneh Tokef (p. 483 in the Rosh Hashanah one, p. 533 in the Yom Kippur one) that “the Chofetz Chaim used to say that if one is satisfied with the bare minimum of food, shelter, and clothing for his family, he may perhaps maintain a similar standard of charity. But if he desires more for himself, he must give more for the needy.”

Artscroll, however, leaves this statement unsourced. Does anyone know where the Chofetz Chaim actually says this?

Comment: ArtScroll tends to leave a lot of things unsourced, from what I understand.

Comment: @ezra They’re doing that less and less in their newer editions, but yes, that’s still very much the case. One of the annoying things about their sefarim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely their source (Ahavat Chessed, sec. [hatimat ha'sefer](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01815.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L4)):

> דידוע דחיוב צדקה וחסד תלוי לפי המקבל ולפי הנותן... בימים הראשונים שהאדם היה מצמצם הנהגת מחיתו מאד, ולא היה מוציא שום דבר על איזה ענין יתר, כי אם על הכרחיות, היה די במעט המעות שהכין לצדקה וחסד לצאת ידי המצוה על פי הדחק; מה שאין כן כהיום, שמצוי, בעונותינו הרבים, שהרבה והרבה מהמעות הולכין על יתרונות מתענוגי בני האדם במלבושים יקרים ודירות יקרות ורבוי המשרתים וכהאי גונא, לא תהא מדת צדקה וחסד, שהיא חיי האדם והצלתו בעולם הזה ובעולם הבא, קל בעיניו מאחד מיתרונותיו

Comment: Makes sense. Here’s your checkmark.